# Exception in "main"java.lang.NullPointerException:Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()"the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, null

I'm having trouble with this code. I copied this code from the book.. What is the problem??

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordCount {
    // minimum number of occurrences needed to be printed

    public static final int OCCURRENCES = 2000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("This program displays the most");
        System.out.println("frequently occurring words from");
        System.out.println("the book Moby Dick.");
        System.out.println();

        // read the book into a map
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("moby.txt"));
        Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = getCountMap(in);

        for (String word : wordCountMap.keySet()) {
            int count = wordCountMap.get(word);
            if (count > OCCURRENCES) {
                System.out.println(word + " occurs " + count + " times.");
            }
        }
    }

    // Reads book text and returns a map from words to counts.
    public static Map<String, Integer> getCountMap(Scanner in) {
        Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String word = in.next().toLowerCase();
            if (wordCountMap.containsKey(word)) {
                // never seen this word before
                wordCountMap.put(word, 1);
            } else {
                // seen this word before; increment count
                int count = wordCountMap.get(word);
                wordCountMap.put(word, count + 1);
            }
        }

        return wordCountMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `.Integer`. instead of `.int`. to avoid automatic unboxing (conversion) and `.NullPointerException`.

Comment: `if (wordCountMap.containsKey(word)) { // never seen this word before` this is the exact opposite of what the comment says. You probably forgot to copy a `!` and this is actually `if (!wordCountMap.containsKey(word))`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes brother here was a bug. Thank you so much)) I copied it from book, like ctrl + c , ctrl + v.. So it's a typo I think in a book. Btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

Map is declared as `Map<String, Integer>` which means values are objects of type `Integer` and they can be `null`. On the other hand, in line `int count = wordCountMap.get(word);` variable `count` is of type `int` which cannot be null. And in this situation Java uses autoboxing to convert `Integer` to `int` calling `Integer.intValue()` under the hood, but what happens if returned value is `null`? Calling any method on `null` will throw `NullPointerException` like you have here.

To summarize: java doesn't know how to convert `null` of `Integer` type into `int` type.

Comment: Ok, but the problem here was *why* that call to `get` returned null. As per my comment, there was a typo in the `if` condition. *That* is the problem with this code.